# IsolatedStorageSettings freeze UI thread WP8

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-8, settings, isolatedstorage, ui-thread

in my app when a user logs in to skydrive and the status changes I am changing 4 settings in IsolatedStorageSettings.

It is done the same as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769510(v=vs.105).aspx

When I modify these 4 values though my UI thread is freezing for a second or two as my progress bar gets choppy. I tried running it in a thread like so but still the same issue.

```
Thread ContactThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(UpdateContact));
ContactThread.Start();
```

Comment: Try to debug and find where it actually freeze.

Comment: And show us `UpdateContact`.